# How to save file with filename alone while downloading files using wget

Tags: shell, azure, azure-storage, wget

when I do wget as below, files are downloaded with filename as **sample.txt?st=2017-07-19T06%3A00%3A00Z"**

```
wget "https://sample.blob.core.windows.net/test/sample.txt?st=2017-07-19T06%3A00%3A00Z"
```

I don't want to use like below as It doesn't suits for my scenario.

```
wget -O $filename -q "https://sample.blob.core.windows.net/test/sample.txt?st=2017-07-19T06%3A00%3A00Z"
```

But I want to save filename as sample.txt when downloading using wget command. How to achieve this?

Comment: The stuff on the end of the file is called the _query_, and [this answer on Superuser](https://superuser.com/a/327254) may be helpful.

Comment: @anubhava It doesn't suits me as I downloading more number of files. I don't want to provide every filename as static. Refer my question.

Comment: You are any providing URL to be downloaded and filename can be derived from that URL easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my understanding is right, following script should work.

```
##set your blob url
url="https://sample.blob.core.windows.net/test/sample.txt?st=2017-07-19T06%3A00%3A00Z"
filename="${url%%[?]*}"; filename="${filename##*/}"

wget -O $filename -q $url
```

Note: If you use this script, your file name could not contain `?`.

Comment: Those external processes aren't necessary.  You can just use shell: `filename="${url%%[?]*}"; filename="${filename##*/}"`

Comment: Thanks very much, it works. I will update my answer.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT What about this => file=$(basename "$url"); filename=$(echo $file|cut -f1 -d"?"). This also works. which is better?

Comment: @karan I think they all works for you. It depend on your like. But all for them, your script name could not contain `?` Because it depends `?` to get file name.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT Ok. Fine.